# Custom warning as printf's "too many arguments for format"

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a way to tell gcc to check argument number in a function based on its parameters, similarly to what it does when giving you a "too many arguments for format" when using printf ?

For example can we have a stdarg-using method with some mandatory argument that would give info on its currently required argument number and have gcc tell us when it's wrong :

```
calculate_mean(4, //Number of arguments
               3, 2, 1, 10); //actual parameters

calculate_mean(5,            //Custom warning from gcc because
               1, 5, 10, 2); //there is one missing argument
```

Giving :

```
# gcc -c file.c -o file.o
gcc: Warning: calculate_mean: Too few arguments (5 required, 4 given)
```

Can it be done from inside the code, from a config file, or is it hardcoded inside the compiler and is not at all possible ?

Comment: I doubt it, but it's an interesting question

Comment: Maybe you can create a [gcc plugin](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, that the support for `printf` style strings is hard-coded into the compiler. In particular, the compiler has a special [`format` function attribute](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html) which can be used to annotate `printf` style functions.

Comment: Thanks! I think the attribute `format (archetype, string-index, first-to-check) ` is what i was looking for. I could not find any attribute about argument numbers though.